# Crontab not sending email

Tags: cron

I am new to crontab. My end goal is to make a git pull command every 10 minutes, but in debugging I tried just sending an email to myself using echo:

```
MAILTO=[my email]

*/10 * * * * echo 'Joseph is the best'
```

I don't get any email though...

Comment: Usually, crontab not sending email error can happen due to missing root mail forwarder or due to the bad settings in the crontab file, maybe you want to recheck your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab does not magicly sends emails out of the box. You need to set up a smtp server first. If you don't want to host your own server you can user google mail and relay all emails over your google account. I use ssmtp and mailutils for this.
A quickguide:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
sudo vim /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

than enter your details at the bottom:

```
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
useSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=username-here
AuthPass=password-here
```

EDIT: for this to work you will have to enable "allow acces to less secure apps" in your google settings